# Subtract value in one data frame from the next value in a second data frame

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that is composed of several datasets (about 146 and counting). two of my columns are labeled "start_time" and "stop_time," which represent the start and stop of a response (i.e., the total duration of the response). 
I need to get the "inter-response time" or the start_time subtracted from the next corresponding value in start_time. Basically if:

```
start_time = [1,4,7]
stop_time = [2,5,8]
```

I need:

```
stop_time[0] - start_time[1]
stop_time[2] - start_time[3]
```

in order to get:

```
iri = [2,2]
```

My code looks like this:

```
iri_t = []
def grps():
    for grp in lset2_name_grps.groups:

        beg_eng_t = pd.DataFrame([lset2_name_grps.stop_time, lset2_name_grps.start_time], columns=['end_t','beg_t'])


        end_t = [i for i in lset2_name_grps.stop_time]
        beg_t = [i for i in lset2_name_grps.start_time]

        beg_t = np.insert(beg_t, len(beg_t),0)
        end_t = np.insert(end_t, 0,0)

        iri_t.append(np.subtract(end_t, beg_t))

#         for i,j in zip(end_t, beg_t):
#             iri_t.append(np.subtract(i,j))


#         lset2_name_grps['iri'] = iri_t
grps()
```

Essentially, it doesn't do anything close to what I'm trying to accomplish and the only out I get is either "Not Implemented" or an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

starts = pd.Series([1, 4, 7])
stops = pd.Series([2, 5, 8])
iri_t = [0]

for i in range(1, len(starts)):
    iri_t.append(starts[i] - ends[i-1])

times_df = pd.concat([starts, stops, pd.Series(iri_t)], axis=1)
```

This creates the following data_frame:

```
   0  1  2
0  1  2  0
1  4  5  2
2  7  8  2
```

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond. In truth both of these solutions worked, but this one ended up being more effective because I had to create the list *before*  I threw the data into a data frame. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what your asking (correct me if I'm wrong) is best accomplished by putting the two columns in a single dataframe, using `shift` to offset one of your columns, then doing an ordinary subtraction.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start_time':[1,4,7], 'stop_time':[2,5,8]})
df.stop_time - df.start_time.shift()
Out[5]: 
0   NaN
1     4
2     4
dtype: float64
```